# Deleting an EF entity efficiently without retrieving inquiry by using .Local and new constructor

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm reading some EF tutorials about deleting items by setting `context.Entry().State` to `EntityState.Deleted`. Two approaches were mentioned when we want to delete an item by `Id`:

1. First call `table.Find(Id)` to return the entity, then set its `EntityState`.

The Find() method will try to locate the entity if it already exists locally, saving a database inquiry, but otherwise it will retrieve the item from the database, wasting an inquiry.

2. Construct a placeholder entity using the Id, then set its `EntityState`

But the problem with #2 is that it won't work if the actual entity with the same Id does already exist locally.

Now assuming we do *not* know if the entity is actually already tracked or not, but we just need to delete it anyway, and we want to guarantee that no wasted retrieval from the database occurs. My question is does this method below work efficiently for this purpose by using the table.Local property:

```
    public int Delete(int id)
    {
        T entityToDelete = table.Local.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

        if (entityToDelete == null)
        {
            entityToDelete = new T() { Id = id};
            
        }

        Context.Entry(entityToDelete).State = EntityState.Deleted;

        return SaveChanges();
    }
```

My thinking is that since .Local will never attempt to retrieve the entity from the database, using it instead of .Find and combine it with the new entity constructor approach could guarantee an entity being deleted without extra inquiry.

However, .Net documentation does say this about Local:

> One final thing to note about Local is that because it is an ObservableCollection performance is not great for large numbers of entities. Therefore if you are dealing with thousands of entities in your context it may not be advisable to use Local.

Can I assume that the overheads of using Local should be smaller than a database inquiry in most cases?

Another approach I can think of is wrapping #2 inside a try/catch, and handle the exception (which implies that the entity is indeed already being tracked) by using .Find() to retrieve the entity locally. How would this compare to the .Local approach?

Comment: Your approach looks good, I've done the same thing in the past although in my case, the Local set either contained the single item I was looking for, or nothing so it wasn't a huge performance hit. Try it out, and see if there is any noticeable impact - it will be application specific, so you're the only one who can answer that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is very good, the performance will be much better than a classic delete, because you're finding an element from a memory collection instead of retrieving the object from database.

**IMPORTANT:** If an entry is attached manually and marked as deleted/modified, and the entry does not exist, a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` exception will be thrown after invoke the `SaveChanges`.

I wanted to recommend **EntityFramework Plus** it provides free functions to improve the EF performance such as Batch Delete, Batch Update, Query Cache and much more (BTW I don't work for EntityFramework Plus). You can read more about EF+ [here](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

Here is a code snip to add the Delete function to your `DbContext`. To make it generic, we need to have an entity base class, let's call it `EntityBase`.

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public int Delete<T>(int id) where T : EntityBase, new()
{
    //using local view/manually attaching
    var item = Set<T>().Local.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);
    if (item is null)
    {
        item = new T { Id = id };
        Set<T>().Attach(item); //WARNING: a DbUpdateConcurrencyException will be thrown is entry does not exist
    }
    Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    return SaveChanges();
}

public int DeleteEfPlus<T>(int id) where T : EntityBase, new()
{
    //using entityframework-plus
    return Set<T>().Where(x => x.Id == id).Delete();
}
```